# Tell Windows program to stick to one monitor

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I use a thin client with two monitors. For some reason the Windows connected to (via XenDesktop) seems to be rather confused about the concept. Lots of programs (including Internet Explorer) open new windows (for example the file open dialogue) on the other monitor (i.e. if the browser window is on monitor 2 a window opened by the browser window opens on monitor 1).

Is there some way to tell Windows to keep all windows of one program on the same monitor?

Comment: I think DisplayFusion allows you to specify where new/specific windows open.